# Gdal Merge of Raster Fails

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-merge

I´m trying to merge several partially overlapping rasters using Gdal Merge in QGIS 3.14.15-Pi. The merge process runs without throwing any errors but the output is incorrect. The output has no defined CRS, extent and the width and height are incorrect. Basically the output fails (cannot even view it). Why is this happening?

I´ve attached a few images of the same.

[image]
[image]

Comment: All the input images are correct? No problems, no corruption etc.? Do they have same projection?

Comment: @ImanolUr Yes, all the input files have no issues. They all have 16 bit unsigned int values with EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 projection with different width, height and extents and 4 bands.

Comment: Try creating a virtualraster with all those layers, and then convert it to tif with Translate.

Comment: @ImanolUr Creating a virtualraster fails as well.

Comment: Then.. i dunno. Only think left i can think of is to try to merge them one by one, and see if it's a specific one that destroys the mosaic.